# Editing iFrame content on the same domain with Laravel 7

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel, iframe

I am attempting to apply CSS and eventually jQuery to a html page in my Laravel storage folder using jQuery I am aware that iFrames need to be on the same domain and both are on my localhost server. I cant change the iFrame content using `$("#IframePage").contents().find('span')` this doesn't seem to work and when i get the length none are being found.
All of my html pages are stored in the storage folder on the backend and they are connected with a storage link.
Thanks.

Comment: Should work fine if you do that query after iframe has loaded . [Working plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/W01O5tXB9ThdATTS?preview)

Comment: yh its in the jquery ready function, still not being found.

Comment: Look at code in demo. Need to use load event listener on frame so that the elements exist when you try looking for them

Comment: Thanks a lot i didn't realize there was a difference between jQuery ready and iframe ready. Thanks

Comment: Iframe has it's own document and it takes time to load the frame page after the frame element is encountered in main page. Main page ready doesn't mean iframe page is ready